# how to split an html with python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Friends, I open an html from Python (a Jupyter notebook) in the following way:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
html = response.read()
```

I am all set to work with this object. However, when I try to clean it with regular expressions it does not work:

```
import re
re.split(r'\W+', html)
```

The last command returns a type error:

> cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I wouldn't use regexp here. This is a debate as old as time. Use a HTML parser instead, such as [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html)

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 for why parsing html with regex is a bad idea. Use Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.decode` from byte into a string.

`html = response.read().decode('utf-8')` then you can use regex for html.